# What is the definition and usage of "tids and bits"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

What is the correct definition and usage of the term "tids and bits"?
I tried googling but nothing turns up, not even a definition.

Comment: Is the phrase you are wondering about "tidbits"?

Comment: what is then, the difference between tidbits and tids and bits, and when to use which? I ask because I find speaking more in tids and bits than tidbits

Comment: I've never heard "tids and bits" in my life. Perhaps you mean "bits and pieces"? You can look up both -- "bits and pieces" and "tidbits" in online dictionaries such as Wiktionary.

Comment: KMC - the reason you can't find a definition for "tids and bits" is because it is not used, whereas "tidbits" and "titbits" are.

Comment: Further to what JAM has said, if you find people using _tids and bits_, please correct them saying that it's _tidbits_. In fact, if you find people using _tidbits_, please correct them saying that it's _titbits_ (the spelling was changed to avoid conjuring up images of mammaries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I have never heard the phrase that you are using being used. The correct usage is tidbits.

Here is the definition that Google gives when you define it:

tidbits plural of tid·bit (Noun)
Noun:
A small piece of tasty food.
A small and particularly interesting item of gossip or information.